# how to modify the reverse url for GET?

Tags: python, django

url: /foo/

href="{% url foo %}"

This is my url. I want to send some GET data with this. So, can I modify the `href` for url: /foo/?bar=1 here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this maybe:

```
href="{% url foo %}?bar=1"
```

Comment: `url` has no provision for GET parameters whatsoever, so not the latter (which is invalid regardless since you can't mix positional and keyword arguments in the same call).

Comment: I'd first handle it in python to make sure there isn't already get data: `if not '?' in foo: foo += '?'` Then on the template side add get data on as singularity says: `href="{% url foo %}&bar=1"`